# How to add up output of the same method multiple time (Sepearate files)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a problem adding up the method output and putting it into another method and then printing it.  My error is that it keeps printing out the first run of the program. Is there a way to record the multiple runs of the method and put it into a double?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    AnnualUse[] fills = {new AnnualUse (1, 1, 9000, 9420, 16.0, 3.11),
                              new AnnualUse (2, 30, 9420, 9840, 16.0, 3.08),
                              new AnnualUse (3, 60, 9840, 10240, 15.23, 3.06)}; 
                              String [] oP = new String [3];
   int diMin=0;
   int diM=0;
   double MPin=0;
   double MPax=0;
   double Primin=0;
   double Primax=0;
   double roundoff1=0;
   double roundoff2=0;
   int minDist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
   int maxDist = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   double minMPG = Double.MAX_VALUE;
   double maxMPG = Double.MIN_VALUE;
   double minPri = Double.MAX_VALUE;
   double maxPri = Double.MIN_VALUE;

   for (int index=0; index<fills.length; index++)
   {
       fills[index].calcDistance();
       fills[index].calcMPG();
       fills[index].calctotalCost();
       fills[index].totalDist();
       fills[index].totalMPG();
       fills[index].totalcost();
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < fills.length; i++) {
       if (fills[i].getDist() < minDist){
           minDist = fills[i].getDist();
           diMin = minDist ;
       }     
       if (fills[i].getDist() > maxDist) {
            maxDist = fills[i].getDist();
            diM = maxDist;
       }
       if (fills[i].getMPG() <minMPG) {
            minMPG = fills[i].getMPG();
            MPin =  minMPG;
       }    
       if (fills[i].getMPG() > maxMPG) {
            maxMPG = fills[i].getMPG();
             MPax = maxMPG;
             roundoff1= Math.round(MPax * 100.0) / 100.0;
       }             
       if (fills[i].getMoolah() < minPri) {
            minPri = fills[i].getMoolah();
            Primin = minPri;
            roundoff2= roundoff2= Math.round(Primin * 100.0) / 100.0;
       }          
       if (fills[i].getMoolah() > maxPri) {
           maxPri = fills[i].getMoolah();
            Primax = maxPri;

       }
   }
   System.out.println("Fill Up  Days  Start Miles  End Miles  Distance  Gallons Used  MPG    Price    Cost");
   for ( int index=0; index< oP.length; index++)
   {
       System.out.printf("%3d %8d %10d %10d %9d %13.1f %8.2f %7.2f %8.2f %n" ,
                         fills[index].getFill(),fills[index].getDay(),
                         fills[index].getStart(),fills[index].getEnd(),
                         fills[index].getDist(), fills[index].getUseofG(),
                         fills[index].getMPG(), fills[index].getCost(),
                         fills[index].getMoolah());
   }
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Minimum:"+"                                 "+diMin+"                  "+MPin+"            "+roundoff2);
   System.out.println("Maximum:"+"                                 "+diM+"                  "+roundoff1+"            "+Primax);
   System.out.print("Totals:");
   for (int index=0; index<1;index++)


       System.out.printf( "%20d %20.2f %10.2f", fills[index].getTotal1(),fills[index].getTotal2(),fills[index].total3());


}
```

first bit of data, from the file I noticed that it's printing out the first run through but  I have no idea why it is not adding the values.This is basically how most of the program is. Sorry for not knowing how to explain most of what is going on, I only know the processes actions and don't know to descriptively describe step by step.

```
class AnnualUse
{
    private int counter,day,ender1, starter1, differance,total1 ;
    private double amount, cost,MPG,Moolah, minDist, 
                   maxDist,minMPG,maxMPG,minPrice,maxPrice,total2,total3;

    AnnualUse (int numberofFills,int days,int starter,int ender,double useofg, double costofg)
    {
        counter=numberofFills;
        day= days;
        starter1=starter;
        ender1=ender;
        amount=useofg;
        cost=costofg;


    }
    public void calcDistance()
    {
        differance=ender1 - starter1;
    }
    public int getDist()
    { 
        return differance;
    }

    public void calcMPG()
    {
        MPG=differance / amount;
    }
    public double getMPG()
    {
        return MPG;
    }
    public void calctotalCost()
    {
        Moolah= amount * cost;
    }
    public double getMoolah()
    {
        return Moolah;
    } 
    public int getFill()
    {
        return counter;
    }
    public int getDay()
    {
        return day;
    }
    public int getStart()
    {
        return starter1;
    }
    public int getEnd()
    {
        return ender1;
    }
    public double getUseofG()
    {
        return amount;
    }
    public double getCost()
    {
        return cost;
    }
    public void totalDist()
    {
        total1=+ differance ;
    }
    public int getTotal1()
    {
        return total1;
    }
    public void totalMPG()
    {
        total2=+MPG;
    }
    public double getTotal2()
    {
        return total2;
    }
    public void totalcost()
    {
        total3=+Moolah;
    }
    public double total3()
    {
        return total3;
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit of formatting would help.

Comment: You're only telling it to print values out of the first `AnnualUse` object, not all of them.  You could remove everything from the 12th to the 16th line (from `}` to `{`) and it will work.

Comment: Please post your entire `AnnualUse` class.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch posted all of the code I have

Comment: @Galaga There are a lot of problems there.

Comment: For example, `total3 = +Moolah;`.

Comment: I think I understand my problem I need to have the total variables = fills.[0]+ fills.[1]+fills[2]. in the main method instead of having separate methods trying to add them up.

Comment: This code may be better off on code review - there is way too much to approach in a simple Q&A format here.

Comment: @TimB Can you link me it for future reference? I don't know any expansiosn of stack exchange

Comment: I put a link in my answer.

Comment: No.  The "code review" site is for code that works, but could possibly be improved in some way.  It's not for bug-hunting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having separate methods to trying adding the total I just needed to make a variable and then add up all of the inputs.

```
 int total1= fills[0].getDist()+fills[1].getDist()+fills[2].getDist();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is too much here for me to give you a specific answer.

It might be worth it for you to clean up the code as much as you can (format it, tidy it, fix as much as you can, etc) and then post it on Code Review for more detailed feedback.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

I'm not going to go through all your code for you but you seem to be asking about totals and averages. To calculate those you just need to loop through your values:

```
 double total1 = 0;
 double total2 = 0;
 for (MyClass mc: theListOfObjects) {
     total1 += mc.getFirstTotal();
     total2 += mc.getSecondTotal();
 }

 System.out.println("Totals: "+total1+", "+total2);
 System.out.println("Mean: "+(total1/theListOfObjects.size())+", "+(total2/theListOfObjects.size()));
```